# n page document or n pages document

Tags: grammar, spelling

When describing a report, should I write:

> this 175 page document contains information about...

or

> this 175 pages document contains information about...

Or possibly with a dash? (175-page document, 175-pages document)?

Comment: I'm really glad you got an answer you liked so quickly, but you might want to wait a while before selecting an answer. This post on meta explains some reasons why: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**175-page document** is correct.

When you combine two or more words (including a number, in this case) to make a single grammatical adjective, you use dashes.  See [here](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/hyphens-with-numbers/).

This rule is commonly violated, so it is quite common to see **175 page document**, but strictly speaking the dash is required for correctness.

You would say "175 pages" when it's not used as an adjective.

> The document has 175 pages.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. This would have been my guess as well, but I am glad to have received a confirmation